# unable to remove marker onTap

Tags: android, dictionary, itemizedoverlay

I'm developing an Android app where a user can add a marker tapping on the screen;
it works, but i have a problem when I want to remove one of the markers by tapping it; here is my code (i followed the NooYawk example):

```
private class PoiOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<MyOverlayItem>{
    private ArrayList<MyOverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<MyOverlayItem>();


    public PoiOverlay() {
        super(null);

        populate();


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        Log.d("toccato",":"+index);
        mOverlays.remove(index);
        doPopulate();
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView view) {
        if (super.onTap(point, view))
            return true;
        int icon;

            if (type==1)
                icon=R.drawable.bluedot;
            else
                icon=R.drawable.reddot;

            MyOverlayItem overlay=new MyOverlayItem(point, ""+id, ""+id, id, icon);
            addOverlay(overlay);
            doPopulate();
            Poi poi=new Poi(id, point, type);
            pois.addLast(poi);
            inserted.addLast(id);

            id+=1;
            return true;

    } 

    public void doPopulate(){
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(MyOverlayItem overlay){
        Drawable drawable=getMarker(overlay.markerInt);
        overlay.marker=drawable;
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I'm able to add markers, but when I try to remove one of them i get an Array out of bounds exception, and I don't know why.

This is the excpetion I got when tapping on a marker:

```
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:       Invalid index 1, size is 1
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
   02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItem(ItemizedOverlay.java:419)

    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.focus(ItemizedOverlay.java:538)
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:455)
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at offscreen.tagger.Main$PoiOverlay.onTap(Main.java:280)
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
    02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at 

com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:347)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:647)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3765)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:905)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:944)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1701)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2093)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1685)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-04 22:17:29.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @user525105: You did not ask a question.

Comment: @user525105: Please edit your question with a stack trace, and indicate where in your code the exception is appearing.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm able to delete only one marker, when I tap another marker I got the errors I posted

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the chain to the superclass (`super.onTap(point, view)`), unless there is specifically something you are expecting the superclass to do for you. That is where your exception is coming from -- the superclass thinks there are more items in the array than there are at present.

Comment: I call the superclass to know if I have tapped an existing overlayitem. Otherwise I create another overlayitem.

Comment: @user525105: Then your bug is in your superclass.

Comment: @user525105: Actually, I reiterate what is in my answer. Delete the `super.onTap()` call from your `onTap()` method.

Comment: If i delete the call to the super class, I'm not able to delete the marker, but only to insert another one!

Comment: @user525105: Oh wait, I see. You're overriding *both* `onTap()` flavors. I missed that. I have no further advice at this time, though.